# VueJS new values to props getting pushed instead of reset

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a problem with my VueJS project. I made a GoogleMaps Component within a DetailView.vue. The maps component uses three props like `driver`, `waypoints` and `stopOver`.

The project structure is:
App.vue containts Login.vue with a route to the main Dashboard View. 
Inside this MainView, I have some menu elements like 'Tours' with a DataTable inside.

Clicking on the datatable row, VueJS presents a DetailView.vue inside a `v-dialog` (using Vuetify).

Inside this DetailView theres another datatable, a switch and at the top, my map component.

```
<LiefermaxMap style="width: 100%; height: 50%;" :waypoints="waypoints" :driver="driverLocation" :stopOver="showCalculatedTour"></LiefermaxMap>
```

`waypoints` and `driverLocation` are **computed** properties, `showCalculatedTour` is a **regular property**, depending on the state of the switch.

Closing this DetailVue Dialog and opening another tour results in pushing another set of waypoints (and driverLocation too) to the property instead of replacing the old ones.

```
waypoints() {
  var points = [];
  if (!this.showCalculatedTour) {
    this.loadnoSpecific.items.items.forEach(element => {
      var p = { lat: element.latitude, lng: element.longitude, done: element.done };
      points.push(p);
    });
  } else {
    this.data.contracts.forEach(element => {
      var c = element.customer.position;
      var p = { lat: c.lat, lng: c.lng, done: element.done }
      points.push(p);
    });
  }
  console.log('points: ' + points)
  return points;
},
driverLocation() {
  const drv = this.data.location;
  const marker = { lat: drv.latitude, lng: drv.longitude };
  return marker;
},
```

Heres a [screenshot of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgxqk.jpg).

What I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Expected behavior: remove all the other waypoints from the previous selected tours
Actual behavior: waypoints are added to the old ones

Tours.vue Example (the view behind the dialog in the screenshot):

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-toolbar flat color="white">
      <v-toolbar-title>Touren</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-data-table style="width: 70vw;"
                  :headers="headers"
                  :items="tours.items.items"
                  :rows-per-page-items="[5,10,20,50,100]"
                  :loading="isLoading"
                  :total-items="totalItems"
                  :must-sort="true"
                  :pagination.sync="pagination"
                  class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="rowClicked(props.item)">
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.loadno }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.tourname }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.kfz }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.driverID }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.device }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.created_at | formatDate }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <v-dialog v-model="showDetail" transition="dialog-bottom-transition" max-width="70vw">
      <TourDetail v-model="showDetail" :data="selectedTour" style="height: 90vh;"></TourDetail>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { settings } from '../settings';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';
import TourDetail from './TourDetail.vue';
export default {
  name: 'tours',
  components: {
    TourDetail
  },
  data() {
    return {
      totalItems: 0,
      selectedTour: {},
      showDetail: false,
      pagination: {
        descending: true,
        page: 1,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        sortBy: 'loadno'
      },
      headers: [ // .. ]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    pagination(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.getDataFromApi();
    },
    tours(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.totalItems = newValue.items.total;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getDataFromApi();
  },
  computed: {
    tours() {
      return this.$store.state.tours.all;
    },
    isLoading() {
      return this.$store.state.tours.loading;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    rowClicked(tour) {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
      };
      const loadno = tour.loadno;
      console.log('LoadNo: ' + loadno);
      this.$store.dispatch('locations/getLoadnoSpecific', { loadno });
      fetch(
        `${settings.apiUrl}/tours/loadno/complete/` + loadno,
        requestOptions
      ).then(response =>
        response.json().then(json => {
          this.selectedTour = json.tour;
          this.showDetail = true;
        })
      );
    },
    getDataFromApi() {
      const perpage = this.pagination.rowsPerPage;
      const page = this.pagination.page;
      const sortby = this.pagination.sortBy;
      const descending = this.pagination.descending;

      this.$store.dispatch('tours/getAll', {
        perpage,
        page,
        sortby,
        descending
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

TourDetail.vue

```
<template>
    <v-flex style="height: 100%;">
      <v-toolbar
          color="primary"
          dark
          flat
          style="z-index: 2; position: absolute;"
        >
          <v-toolbar-title class="justify-center">Fahrer: {{ data.driver.firstname + ' ' + data.driver.lastname  }} &nbsp; | &nbsp;  iPad: {{ data.device }} &nbsp; | &nbsp; Fahrzeug: {{ data.kfz }}</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
      <v-card style="height: 100%; position: relative;">
        <LiefermaxMap style="width: 100%; height: 50%;" :waypoints="waypoints" :driver="driverLocation" :stopOver="showCalculatedTour"></LiefermaxMap>
        <v-layout row wrap style="height: 50%;">
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card style="height: 100%;">
          <v-switch v-model="showCalculatedTour" :label="switchLabel" style="position: absolute; right: 10%;"></v-switch>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="data.contracts"
          :expand="expand"
          :rows-per-page-text="perPageText"
          style="padding: 5%;"
        >
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            ...
          </template>
          <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
            <v-card>
              <div>
                ...
              </div>
            </v-card>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
import LiefermaxMap from '../components/LiefermaxMap.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    LiefermaxMap
  },
  computed: {
    loadnoSpecific() {
      return this.$store.state.locations.loadnoSpecific;
    },
    waypoints() {
      var points = [];
      if (!this.showCalculatedTour) {
        this.loadnoSpecific.items.items.forEach(element => {
          var p = { lat: element.latitude, lng: element.longitude, done: element.done };
          points.push(p);
        });
      } else {
        this.data.contracts.forEach(element => {
          var c = element.customer.position;
          var p = { lat: c.lat, lng: c.lng, done: element.done }
          points.push(p);
        });
      }
      console.log('points: ' + points)
      return points;
    },
    driverLocation() {
      const drv = this.data.location;
      const marker = { lat: drv.latitude, lng: drv.longitude };
      return marker;
    },
    switchLabel() {
      return this.showCalculatedTour ? 'errechnete Route' : 'gefahrene Route';
    }
  },
  props: ['data'],
  data() {
    return {
      showCalculatedTour: false,
      googleWaypoints: [],
      drivenWaypoints: [],
      expand: false,
      perPageText: 'pro Seite',
      completeTourLoading: true,
      completeTour: [{}],
      selectedContract: {},
      headers: [... ]
    };
  },
  methods: { ... }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
// ...
</style>
```

And LiefermaxMap component:

```
<template>
  <div v-show="mapInitialized" class="liefermaxmap" id="liefermaxmap" ref="liefermaxmap"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LiefermaxMap',
  props: ['waypoints', 'driver', 'stopOver'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      mapName: 'liefermaxmap',
      markerCoordinates: [{}],
      mapInitialized: false,
      directionsService: null,
      directionsDisplay: null,
      vueGMap: null,
      bounds: null,
      markers: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    waypoints(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log('Waypoints changed, count: ' + newValue.length);
      console.log(newValue)
      this.setWaypoints();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createGoogleMaps: function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let gmap = document.createElement('script');
        gmap.src =
          'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX';
        gmap.type = 'text/javascript';
        gmap.onload = resolve;
        gmap.onerror = reject;
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(gmap);
      });
    },
    initGoogleMaps: function() {
      const localOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: this.driver,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
        },
        panControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
      };

      this.vueGMap = new google.maps.Map(
        this.$refs['liefermaxmap'],
        localOptions
      );
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      var drivermarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.driver),
        map: this.vueGMap,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/truck.png'
      });
      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.vueGMap);
      this.mapInitialized = true;
    },
    addMarker(latLng, color) {
      let url = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
      url += color + '-dot.png';

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.vueGMap,
        position: latLng,
        icon: {
          url: url
        }
      });
    },
    setWaypoints() {
      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.vueGMap);
      var googleWaypoints = [];
      this.waypoints.forEach(element => {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng);
        var wp = { location: pos, stopover: false };
        googleWaypoints.push(wp);
        console.log(element)
        if (element.done == true) {
          this.addMarker(pos, 'green')
        } else {
          this.addMarker(pos, 'red')
        }
      });

      var i = 0;
      var j = 0;
      var temparray = [];
      var chunk = 15;

      for (i = 0, j = googleWaypoints.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
        temparray = googleWaypoints.slice(i, i + chunk);
        var request = {
          origin: 'XXX',
          destination: 'XXX',
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          waypoints: temparray
        };
        this.directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    googleMapsFailedToLoad() {
      this.vueGMap = 'Error while loading map';
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initGoogleMaps();
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.liefermaxmap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use watch instead of computed. And in mounted assign value to your data fields. You will need mounted for first initialize and watch for every time data changes. Good luck.

Comment: Can you specify whats your expected behaviour and your actual behaviour? its not clear what the problem is. When you switch from one tour to the other, do you see the old datapoints in the map?

Comment: Also, can you update the question with the template to see how you are showing/hiding the dialog?

Comment: I updated my question with the code of the components

Comment: maybe i just dont see it - but where are you deleting the map modifications? - oh in mounted - there it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### vue reuses components - use `key` to force mounting

---

Change

```
<LiefermaxMap style="width: 100%; height: 50%;" :waypoints="waypoints" :driver="driverLocation" :stopOver="showCalculatedTour"></LiefermaxMap>
```

to

```
<LiefermaxMap style="width: 100%; height: 50%;" :key="waypoints" :waypoints="waypoints" :driver="driverLocation" :stopOver="showCalculatedTour"></LiefermaxMap>
```

use `key` to tell vue not to reuse the component - so mounted can be triggered,

or move your `initMap` method.